# Check if picture is the same

Tags: php

Is it possible to check if two picture are identical with php?

(I want to check if a picture of an event from facebook is the dafault, or not)

Thanks, John

Comment: How would you define "identical"?  If you compare pixel by pixel, and one is off, does that mean they aren't identical?

Comment: can you check that the urls are the same?

Comment: facebook api gives different urls for the same picutre

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use a hashing algorithm and compare the two hashes:

```
if ( sha1_file ( $file1 ) === sha1_file ( $file2 ) ) {
  // They're identical
} else {
  // They're not
}
```

This uses [sha1_file](http://php.net/sha1_file), but you could use any hashing algorithm.. MD5 for instance

Comment: I think this could be the most efficient one.

Comment: Why use === both types will always be equal ?

Comment: Does this hashes the content of the `$file1` and `$file2`, like real images, or the paths to those images?

Answer (score 1):

Identical, as in bit for bit?  You may be able to simply hash the files, for a (fairly) quick comparison.

If you want to compare visually, that is a completely different matter.